# Is there a total score for the whole Stack Exchange stack?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges, profile-page, summary

On some days, I'd like to see a summary of my learning & share the knowledge achievements in total, regardless the topic.

Closest thing I found is going to the Stack Exchange Network Profile and hitting the "accounts" tab - https://stackexchange.com/users/2058265/jave-web?tab=accounts + little coding myself.

Still though, everything there, including the graph on the other tab, is by topic.

**Is there somewhere a total score page combining every precious stat from all Stack Exchange Network sites - all points, coins, badges, reputations, impact, questions, answers, ...?**

Comment: I had to create a manual version of this on google sheets: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hM9puAibepGuQclUo1ryO8u3tkQPaMqligEw8eA-WEI/edit#gid=0

Comment: [Flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/2058265/jave-web?tab=flair) shows the net reputation and badges from sites where you have rep (>200). But for impact, questions and answers, I think you have to do on your own

Comment: @Ak. Totally missed that, such an important info given in such a ***side*** note! :-O

Comment: @Rob coins where just a random word meaning "and whatever else", badges kinda look like that too, otherwise I specifically asked about combined/groupbyed view, I already know how to get the stats for each individual site **= that is not what this Q is about** :)

Answer (score 5):

The closest you can get to what you want in one place without writing your own  code is the global flair:

[image]

The global flair sums the reputation and badges on all sites where you have 200 reputation or more.

Getting to see your own flair is pretty simple:

1. Go to your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=flair) (either directly from this link or by clicking "network profile" link in any of your site profiles)
2. Go to the "flair" tab, the right-most tab in the page. (visible only when viewing own profile)
3. Profit.

To see the flair of other user (like I did with yours, above) it's bit more tricky:

1. Find the user's network profile ID, by going to their network profile (accessibly from any site profile) and taking it from the URL. (the number after the `https://stackexchange.com/users/`)
2. Manually put the number in this URL:

   `https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/[network ID here].png`
3. Browse to the above URL or use in image tag/markdown to see the flair of the other user.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer to query for some 'categories'.

I've combined the most common data that is available and is not anonymized. The [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1370819?accountid=2058265) can be extended by adding extra unions.

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

create table #dbs( name nvarchar(max)
                 , userid int)

select @sql = 'insert into #dbs ' + string_agg(concat(
N' 
select ''',convert(nvarchar(max),quotename(name)),N''' [site]
    , id
from ', convert(nvarchar(max),quotename(name)), N'.dbo.users u 
where u.accountid = ##accountid?2058265##
')
,N' union all ')
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5

exec (@sql)




select @sql = concat(N'
select name [Category] 
     , sum([cnt]) [Grand total per cat.]
from (' ,
string_agg(concat(
N'
select ''', name ,N''' [site]
    , pt.Name 
    , count(*) [cnt]
from ', name, N'.dbo.posts p
inner join ', name , N'.dbo.posttypes pt 
      on pt.id = p.posttypeid
inner join ', name , N'.dbo.users u 
      on u.id = p.owneruserid
where p.owneruserid = ', userid, N'
group by name
union all
select ''',name ,N''' [site]
    , vt.Name 
    , count(*) [cnt]
from ', name, N'.dbo.votes v
inner join ', name, N'.dbo.votetypes vt 
      on vt.id = v.votetypeid
where v.userid = ', userid, N'
group by name
union all
select ''',name,N''' [site]
    , case b.class 
      when 1 then case when b.tagbased = 1 then ''Gold Tag badge'' else ''Gold badge'' end 
      when 2 then case when b.tagbased = 1 then ''Silver Tag badge'' else ''Silver badge'' end
      when 3 then case when b.tagbased = 1 then ''Bronze Tag badge'' else ''Bronze badge'' end
      end 
    , count(*) [cnt]
from ', name, N'.dbo.badges b
where b.userid = ', userid, N'
group by b.class, b.tagbased
union all
select ''',name ,N''' [site]
    , ''Comments ''
    , count(*) [cnt]
from ', name, N'.dbo.comments c
where c.userid = ', userid, N'
union all
select ''',name ,N''' [site]
    , ''Upvotes cast''
    , upvotes [cnt]
from ', name, N'.dbo.users u
where u.id = ', userid, N'
union all
select ''',name ,N''' [site]
    , ''Downvotes cast''
    , downvotes [cnt]
from ', name, N'.dbo.users u
where u.id = ', userid, N'
union all
select ''',name ,N''' [site]
    , ''Reputation''
    , reputation [cnt]
from ', name, N'.dbo.users u
where u.id = ', userid, N'
union all
select ''',name ,N''' [site]
    , ''Suggested edits''
    , count(*) [cnt]
from ', name, N'.dbo.suggestededits s
where s.owneruserid = ', userid, N'

')
,N' union all ')
, N') data
group by name
order by 2 desc
')
from #dbs

print @sql
exec (@sql)
```

When run today this is the result for your account:

[image: categories with count]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday.
Give a big shout-out to [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) for the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) she wrote.
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: "adding extra unions" - I read that as "adding extra unicorns". :D

Comment: This it the most complete one so far - is there a way of getting the IMPACT? :)

Comment: @jave.web no, impact is very volatile, not stored in SEDE and to calculate it it requires a beast of a query while that result is most likely still off due to missing public data.